# Absolute position of bottom div does not change when window is resized

Tags: css

So here's the problem,

Basically when you resize the window, the size of the relative div is meant to shrink down and the height is meant to shrink aswell, changing the bottom right position of the div.  However for the life of me I cannot make the bottom of "absolute" change position in response to resizing the window.

Any help is appreciated! HALP!

```
<style type="text/css">

    .relative{
        position:relative;
        top:100px;
        left:100px;
        min-width:250px;
        max-width:500px;

        height:500px;
        background-color:blue;
    }


    .absolute{
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        bottom:10%;
        right:10%;
        vertical-align: baseline;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="relative">
        relative
        <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: It is not clear. Exactly what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, when resizing the window the blue div (relative) will change in size depending on if you shrink or expand the window. When the blue div size changes you want to keep the red div (absolute) in the bottom right position. Is this correct?

If so you need to make the blue div width 100% and it's parents width's 100% all the way up until you hit the html element.

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.relative{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    min-width:250px;
    max-width:500px;

    max-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
}


.absolute{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    bottom:10%;
    right:10%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/Nr2W7/)

Note: On the fiddle, move the result section bar (the bar that splits the css and the results) up and down to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed size `height:500px;` for the parent element. 
This means Width is being changed on resize but height doesn't.
You should input for example:

```
min-height:250px;
max-height:500px;
```

Here is the Fiddle showing the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/324e2/